# How to change the opacity of background without changing the content of it?

Tags: html, css

I don't know how to make `background-image` opacity 0.5 and the content full opacity.

```css
.about-section {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  /*background: #eee;*/
  background: url(../images/about.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<section id="about" class="about-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="head">About Us</h1>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398224/set-background-image-with-transparent-color-and-also-make-the-height-of-the-imag/44398374#44398374

Comment: You can't with CSS, use a semi-transparent image

Comment: The best solution would be to simply change your image to be more transparent. Other than that, you can try keeping the image as a seperate element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Background Opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422949/css-background-opacity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you're after?

```css
  .about-section {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .background {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(https://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/976/media/images/83351000/jpg/_83351965_explorer273lincolnshirewoldssouthpicturebynicholassilkstone.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    opacity: 0.3;
    
  }
```

```html
<section id="about" class="about-section">
  <div class="background">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="head">About Us</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: No worries @Y.EzzEldin

Answer (score 2):

You can use pseudo elements to get it
just like following

```css
.about-section {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  /*background: #eee;*/
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

.about-section::after {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); /*Change as your need */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<section id="about" class="about-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="head">About Us</h1>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `::before`´-pseudo-element.

```css
.about-section {
  position:relative; /* Notice this */
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.about-section::before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  background: #000; /* change to whatever you want */
  opacity:0.3;
}
```

```html
<section id="about" class="about-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="head">About Us</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, CSS does not offer that possibility (unless your background is just a colour, in which case you can use `rgba()`).

To achieve this, you can place your `.about-section` in `position: relative;` and create a `<div>` inside it (preferably as the first child, or even better, as a `::before` pseudo-element) absolutely positioned, with full width and height. You can then tweak its opacity as you wish without affecting the content.